# Extract pair ( VERB-Noun) from list

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, part-of-speech

I want to extract pair (verb-noun) from each row i want to add other column and put all pair there im using Eron dataset i worked the first part preprocessing (remove number, punctuation...) and know i want to detect (verb-noun) any help please

```
import spacy
import numpy as np
nlp = spacy.load('en')

a=nlp(str(train['text_lemmatized'])
noun_adj_pairs=[]
for i,token in enumerate(a):
    if token.pos not in ('VERB','NOUN'):
        continue
    for j in range(i+1,len(a)):
        if a[j].pos_ == 'NOUN':
           noun_adj_pairs.append((token,a[j]))
        break

noun_adj_pairs
```

[image: data]

Comment: Please add example input and expected outputs clearly. P.S. Please DO NOT post images of your data as there is no way for me to copy and use it. It increases the resistance for people to answer your questions as they need to type out the data.